# Servo constantly rotates

Tags: servo

I´m reading some data from XML with my ESP32 and want to control servos with it. For the ESP32 I needed to use a different library which works fine with my MS18 microservo. However, when I use my MG996R it works for some time but sometimes it randomly starts to keep rotating. I can only stop it by unplugging the powersupply from the servo. The servo works on 50Hz and like I said I use a external powersupply. I hope somebody can help me with this.

Comment: if the servo goes crazy it could be noise on the servo supply. a working servo *never* rotates constantly if the control signal is stable. when it does that try to disconnect only the control lead, if it doesn't stop the servo controller is suffering from something i.e. it's not a software issue

Comment: When I disconnect the datacable it still rotates

Comment: I'm using the pwm directly from the ESP. Could that be a problem? Do I need a control module?